# $A propriety of a given fuction

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

Let $f \colon [0; 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{x} & x \in (0, 1]\\
0 & x= 1
\end{cases}
$$

Is it true that  $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: The derivative exists for all $x\neq0$. At $x=0$ $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1/x}{e^{1/x}}$. Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{-1/x^2}{e^{1/x}(-1/x^2)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}}=0$, by L'Hospital so we have $f'(0)=0$. Since $f$ is differentiable everywhere, it is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Differentiable everywhere does not imply absolutely convergent.

Comment: @S.Pek the continuity of its derivative in the compact $[0,1]$ does.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Check that $f$ is continuous. Then it is easy to observe, that its derivative is bounded.
Indeed: 
$$
f'(x)=-e^{-1/x}\frac1{x^2}=-\frac{1}{x^2e^{1/x}}=-\frac{(1/x)^2}{e^{1/x}},
$$ which tends to 0, when $x\to0+$. Hence the derivative is bounded on $(0,1]$, so $f$ is absolutely continuous on $(0,1]$ and, as a result, on $[0,1]$.

*Remark*: If for somebody it is not a simple conclusion of continuity at $0$: is it obvious that $e^{-x}$ is absolutely continuous on $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: why would $f$ not be continuous?

Comment: @gt6989b It is. But checking it is probably expected, because the rest is a simple conclusion.

Comment: yes $f$ is continuous since $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ and $lim_{x\to 0^{+}}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=0$, but why it is absolute continuous ?

Comment: I fail to see how, given that $f$ is continuous, it is a *simple conclusion* that it is absolutely continuous

Comment: @Siwar What abous present extension of the hint?

Comment: @gt6989b Only theoretically possible point , where we can have problem with derivative, because of discontinuity, is 0.

Comment: @ Przemysław Scherwentke, can you please detail the answer i am a little bit confused, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @Siwar Is the present version enough?

Comment: @thanks Przemysław Scherwentke, i have an other question is it true that $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0; 1]$? if so how do you see that?

Comment: Absolute Convergence implies Bounded Variation